# How to start timer that doesn't stop when activity closes

Tags: android, timer

I would like to have an activity. In this activity I would like to have a button. When this button is pressed I would like a timer to start and be displayed "00:00:01". So far I have accomplished this using a Chronometer. What I would like to do now is to have this timer stay active (continue to count) even when the activity is not running.

So basically, i click a button and start the timer and it is counting and then I close the activity. I would then start the application again and in this activity I can see the counter counting and showing the elapsed time from when I clicked the button. For example, if I closed the activity and then came back 30 minutes later, the timer would show that time.

Can someone show me how to accomplish this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: a) just store the starting moment into SQLite b) create accompanying service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save start systime in preferences and read it when activity restarts. There is no point to make timers, handlers etc. if you just have to write down start time and display

`systime-starttime`

every 250 ms (or choose your own period)

Comment: That sounds good. I was doing more thinking and thought about this, using preferences to store the start time and when the activity starts grabbing that time and setting the Chronometer to that time. Is using preferences or SQLite the most efficient and correct way to do this or is there some build in class that can accomplish the same task more efficiently?

Comment: SP seems more convenient in this situation